# add attributes to a react component passed into another component via props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an element wrapper to get the height of the parent which I need to pass on to child elements.

I am getting and setting the height via a `ref`

I am passing the child into the parent and need to pass the height on to the child.

```
class WrapElement extends React.Component<{element: any},any> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.getHeight = this.getHeight.bind(this);
        this.setHeight = this.setHeight.bind(this);
        if (this.props.element) window.addEventListener('resize', this.setHeight);

    }
    getHeight() {
        let { clientHeight }: any = this.refs.elemWrapper;
        return clientHeight;
    }
    setHeight() {
        this.setState({wrapperHeight: this.getHeight()})
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setHeight();
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return !this.state || this.getHeight() !== this.state.wrapperHeight;
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.setHeight();
    }
    render() {
        return <div
            ref="elemWrapper"
            >
            {this.props.element? <this.props.element wrapperHeight={this.state.wrapperHeight} /> : 'no render'}
        </div>
    }
}
```

I'm sure `<this.props.element />` is not valid, but I can't figure out how I would pass the `wrapperHeight` on to the children.

Comment: Are you saying that you are receiving data from one child and want to pass it to other?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `React.cloneElement` to clone the element and pass the extra props,

```
  {
       this.props.element? React.cloneElement(
         this.props.element, 
         { wrapperHeight: this.state.wrapperHeight
       }): 
       'no render'
   }
```